# Condensing jQuery instead of writing code for each popup

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to show popups over hover areas on a site:

HTML

```
<map id='_Image-Maps_1201306032036494' name='Image-Maps_1201306032036494'>
     <area shape='rect' coords='35,352,64,380' rel='one1'/>
</map>
<div id='one1' class='popBox'><div class='inside'><h4>Newspapers and mail piling up</h4><p><strong>Tip:</strong> When you go on vacation, call your local post office and newspaper provider to put your mail and newspaper delivery on hold. Or ask a reliable neighbor to pick it up for you.</p></div></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('area[rel="one1"]').hover(
   function(){
   $('#one1').show();
   },function(){
   $('#one1').hide();
});
```

However I have quite a few areas that I need this to work for. The area rel is always the same as the ID on the div that needs to pop up. Instead of writing code for each individual popup, is there a way to set it up so whenever you mouse over an area on the image map, it shows the popup with the same rel as the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I'd suggest:

```
$('area[rel]').hover(function(){
    // you may find that this.rel works, instead of
    // '$(this).attr('rel'), but I've not tried it.
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
}, function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
});
```

[Confirmed by Roko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927165/condensing-jquery-instead-of-writing-code-for-each-popup/16927199#comment24436872_16927199) (in comments, below) that the use of `this.rel` works, which is cheaper than using jQuery to retrieve the same value/property; which gives, instead:

```
$('area[rel]').hover(function(){
    $('#' + this.rel).show();
}, function(){
    $('#' + this.rel).hide();
});
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Simplicity sake I would suggest: `$('area[rel]').hover(function(){
    $('#' + this.rel).toggle();
});` **Tested.**